# Why can't I knit in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr

I have successfully written my code in R script, but when I try to knit in Rmarkdown, I get the following error. "

[image]

I have tried:

1. Installing packages into Rmarkdown
2. Using different environments(R studio cloud and desktop R) with the exact same result. I think that means there is a problem with my code, but only when I try to knit. If I run the code in rmarkdown, everything works. But I can't knit to html.

**Below is my script code:**

```
View(Daily_log_weight)

myweight <- Daily_log_weight%>%
  clean_names

View(myweight)

#Example: ggplot(data=heartrate_seconds_clean) + geom_bar(mapping=aes(y=value), color='purple')

#Lesson learned: Only things pertaining to an function should go into that function. Geom_point,  labs, etc.

chart1 <- ggplot(data=myweight) + geom_point(mapping=aes(x=day,y=morning_weight), color='orange') + labs(x="The Day", y="My Morning Weight", title = "My Awesome Weightloss Journey", subtitle = "By Naomi Narcisse")

chart1


chart2 <- ggplot(data=myweight) + geom_smooth(mapping=aes(x=day,y=after_workout_weight), color='turquoise') + labs(x="The Day", y="After Workout Weight", title = "Continued.. . After workout", subtitle = "By Naomi Narcisse")

chart2


chart3 <- ggplot(data=myweight) + geom_jitter(mapping=aes(x=morning_weight,y=after_workout_weight), color='dark green', fill='light pink') + labs(x="My Morning Weight", y="My After-Workout Weight", title = "Comparison Weightloss", subtitle = "By Naomi Narcisse")

chart3
```

Comment: Look at line 22 of your RMD script - that's where the error is coming from. Perhaps something to do with installing a package?

Comment: it is also necessary to avoid putting a "view" on a RMarkdown code, because it just allows you to open a table on R

Comment: You may have installed the libraries in your R session, but make sure you add `library(PACKAGE_NAME)` at the start of your scripts. Does it work when you run each line of code one by one, but then errors out when you try and run the whole script at once?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. So far, I've found that the knit works with the "cars" data. But not with my csv imported file. I'll keep working on it but any other advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, reinstall R, RStudio and all your packages. Windows users should install Rtools as well which will deal with package installation.